# Lagrange Interpolation as generalized polynom

Tags: interpolation, linear-regression, lagrange-interpolation

I need to write an algorithm that constructs a function of the form

$f(x) = \sum_i^n q_i x^i$
that exactly goes through the points $p_i = (a_i, b_i)$.

In general building such a function is not the problem since the Lagrange Interpolation can be used. However the form is not correct and it still needs to be rearranged.
While it is possible to throw a equation simplifier on the Lagrange Interpolation form, this is no elegant solution :)

TLDR; How would one compute the $q_i$ (something othen then Lagrange would also work fine, it just needs to be in polynomal form)

Comment: Can you substitute in the points then solve the resulting linear equations for the $q_i$? Do you have a built in solver for $Aq=b$?

Comment: There are [many methods](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Polynomial_interpolation#Constructing_the_interpolation_polynomial) to construct the interpolation polynomial of degree at most $n$ through a collection of points $\bigl\{ (x_0, y_0), \dots (x_n, y_n) \}$, where the $x_i$ are pairwise distinct. You can, for example, invert the Vandermonde determinant. There are also [efficiencies that can be exploited](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Polynomial_interpolation#Interpolations_as_linear_combinations_of_values) if your $x_i$ are equally spaced.

Answer (score 0):

The principle is to write a sum with coefficients the values  $a_k = f(x_k)$ multiplied by rationals of products of linear factors such that $r_k(x_k)=1$ and zero on all other points.

$$P(x)  =\sum_{k=1}^n f(x_k) \frac{\prod_{l=1}^n (x-x_l)}{\prod_{l=1}^n (x_k-x_l)}$$